# How to prevent event firing on drag and drop of columns in JavaFX TableView

Tags: windows, spring-boot, java-8, javafx-8

In my Spring Boot JavaFX application I have multiple TableViews. The user is allowed to reorder the columns by using the default drag-and-drop functionality. I also have a listener to detect that another row in one of those TableViews is selected and take some action accordingly:

```
/*
 * Processing when a selection in a table changes.
 */ 
getTableView().getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    this.detailsController.get().showDetails(newValue);
});
```

Problem is that this listener gets activated when a column is dragged and then dropped (on the drop part of the action). This has undesired side effects, since the variable newValue is 'null' in that case (which in itself is a valid value for processing, I just don't want to pass that value when dropping a column after dragging). Is there a way to bypass this listener when the column is dropped?

I have tried various ways to catch the drag-drop events, but to no avail...I was thinking I could deactivate the listener when the drag starts and reactivate after the drop is done.

Here is some sample code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestDragDrop extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(createData());
        
        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == null) {
                System.out.println("===>>> Oops");
            } else {
                System.out.println("===>>> Hi there " + newValue.getFirstName());
            }
        });

        VBox checkBoxes = new VBox(5);
        checkBoxes.getStyleClass().add("controls");

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setTop(checkBoxes);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col;
    }

    private List<Person> createData() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public final String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setEmail(final String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Select a row in the table: ===>>> Hi there .... is output to the console. Now drag the first column to a different place in the table: ===>>> Oops is output to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way to prevent this is by adding a buffer to prevent changes for a period of time once the column has been released.

In my case I used 50ms as the buffer because it will be hard for a person to finish dragging and click on a name in that time as it comes out to .05 Seconds in my testing this worked fine(No null were passed) but increase/decrease as you see fit

Here I initialize the PauseTransition which will fire after a given time

```
private final PauseTransition bufferReset = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(50));
private boolean isBuffering = false;
```

Once initialized set the variable to flip back to no longer buffering

```
bufferReset.setOnFinished(event -> isBuffering = false);
```

The next block of code is where we flip the buffer variable after the column has been released and start the timer to flip the variable back

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    for (Node header : table.lookupAll("TableHeaderRow")) {
        if(header instanceof TableHeaderRow) {
            header.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> {
                isBuffering = true;
                bufferReset.play();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

From there wrap your code in a isBuffering if statement

```
if(!isBuffering) {
    if (newValue == null) {
        System.out.println("===>>> Oops");
    } else {
        System.out.println("===>>> Hi there " + newValue.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

Full Code(Not including the person class):

```
public class TestDragDrop extends Application {

    private final PauseTransition bufferReset = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(50));
    private boolean isBuffering = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(createData());

        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(!isBuffering) {
                if (newValue == null) {
                    System.out.println("===>>> Oops");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("===>>> Hi there " + newValue.getFirstName());
                }
            }
        });

        bufferReset.setOnFinished(event -> isBuffering = false);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            for (Node header : table.lookupAll("TableHeaderRow")) {
                if(header instanceof TableHeaderRow) {
                    header.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> {
                        isBuffering = true;
                        bufferReset.play();
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        VBox checkBoxes = new VBox(5);
        checkBoxes.getStyleClass().add("controls");

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        root.setTop(checkBoxes);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col;
    }

    private List<Person> createData() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

}
```

Comment: Matt, you saved the day! Works like a charm. I am still wondering though why the drag-and-drop functionality triggers the selectedItemProperty listener, I mean, there is no change to the selected item, just the columns being moved around...